# Is it possible to execute a load test, which uses a web test plugin by using MSTest command line?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, mstest, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a web performance test, which uses web test plugin. Based on this web performance test, I created a load test. When I run the load test from the Visual Studio 2013, the load test runs correctly on all my remote agents. However when I run the same test by using MSTest command line, I get an error indicating that the PlugIn (C#) was not loaded. My question is whether it is possible to execute a load test (with plugin) by using the command line MSTest? If yes, then what I need to do to get rid of the error?

Please note that I have already referenced the plugin in my visual studio projects (both web performance project and load test projects)

Thx
Here is the error that I get:

Run has the following issue(s):

```
  Could not run load test 'ABC' on agent 'XYZ': Could not load
  file or assembly 'PlugIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null
 ' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file  specified.
  Could not load file or assembly 'PlugIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Visual Studio runs a test from within a solution it understands deployment items, such as DLLs for plugins and it deploys them automatically. By contrast **mstest.exe** does not do any automatic deployment. Hence you need to deploy the files yourself. That is commonly done via the "deployment" sections of a `.testrunconfig` or a `.testsettings` file.

Having specified the DLLs to be deployed in one of these two file types, add the corresponding `/testsettings:{file name}` or `/runconfig:{file name}` options into the call of **mstest.exe**.

See, for example, section 3 of [this Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2008/12/22/running-web-and-load-tests-from-the-command-line.aspx).